# MapFragment does not show map

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

I've looked through the documentation and I can't find any reason why the MapFragment only shows a grey screen with the Google logo on the lower left hand side. In my manifest, I have the appropriate meta-data on the application level (GMS version number and the api key). The module gradle file has all the needed dependencies. The error might be in the java code, which is as follows:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Polyline polyline;
    private PolylineOptions mPLO;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        //mPLO = new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true);;
        //polyline = mMap.addPolyline(mPLO);

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
       // updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        //getDeviceLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       // mPLO.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        // A step later in the tutorial adds the code to get the device location.
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
        }
    }

}
```

The logcat shows the following errors

```
234-31464/com.gjd.capstone E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-12 15:30:12.967 30234-31464/com.gjd.capstone E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                            API Key: <Redacted>
                                                                            Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 47:B9:AC:D7:30:4D:AB:2D:6E:29:06:99:24:B1:7C:07:95:0A:8B:96;com.gjd.capstone
```

I have even looked into the developers console to see if the api was disabled, it wasn't. I'm still not sure what to do. I'm not sure if "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled, I couldn't find the option for it.

Comment: Have you setup API key?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can see it in the manifest and in the google_maps_api.xml file. When I generated the mapfragment that file was made automatically I followed the instructions to get the api key and pasted where I needed it to be.

Comment: Please upload logcat output

Comment: the logcat info was added Parth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. After I created the MapsActivity, I changed the the package of the java file but I did not change the package name in the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

By opening the project on another PC, the MapFragmant was no longer displayed. To solve the problem I signed my application with the keystore on my pc.

Under xamarin
1. Create an archive of my application (an apk)
2. Create a keystore if it is not already done
3. Click on Distribute
4. Choose Ad Hoc
5. Choose the keystore
6. Click on save as and save to app
7. Rebuild project